# erro ao tentar download de arquivo no codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

eu fiz uma função para upload de arquivos e esta funciona corretamente,
agora na minha view adicionei um link para fazer o download do arquivo.

link na view:

```
<td><?php echo anchor("propostas/download/{$id}/{$record->nomepessoal}", "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></i>", ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block', 'name' => 'baixar']); ?></td>
```

e esta é a `function` do  `controller`

```
// baixar anexo
public function download($id, $nomepessoal) {

    $this->load->helper('download');

    $nomearquivo = $nomepessoal."_".$id.".zip";
    $path = file_get_contents(base_url()."anexos/".$nomearquivo);

    force_download($path, null); // start download`
}
```

Erro na função `file_get_contents`:

> Message: file_get_contents(http://localhost/sistema/anexos/arquivo_17.zip): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Obs: o arquivo existe e o nome está correto.

Answer (score 2):

Valide se seu .htaccess está configurado e funcionando. Ele deve direcionar as chamadas para `index.php`, mas se for acessar um arquivo existente ele não deve direcionar para o `index`. Garanta que as linhas abaixo existam no seu arquivo `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Eu defino uma regra `Um sistema em cada VirtualHost` e crio um domínio interno no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, tipo http://sistema1.local/ e configuro meu arquivo `/etc/hosts` para minha máquina reconhecer esse domínio, por isso, nunca escrevi a linha RewriteBase :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editei conforme sua orientação. Vou me atentar a esses detalhes, apesar que estava focado em fazer funcionar com o que ele apresentou e a url do anexo é `http://localhost/sistema/anexos/arquivo_17.zip)` então acredito que o RewriteEngine deve apontar para o diretório `/sistema` de localhost não está certo?

Comment: Deixa eu explicar de outra maneira: se `sistema` for o "root" do CI3, então esta certo, mas é redundante, vai funcionar com ou sem, no entanto mesmo que seja redundante e não afete em nada, no servidor/hospedagem o esquema de pasta pode estar totalmente diferente e então lá sim pode falhar. Não tem necessidade de usar RewriteBase a não ser que vc queira que de fato os Rules apontem pra uma pasta totalmente diferente da atual. +1 pra sua resposta, agora acho que ficou otima.

Comment: Perfeito! Acho que enfim entendi do que se trata o RewriteBase e porque sempre funcionou sem para mim, eu nunca quis que ele apontasse para outro lugar! Obrigado.